# What can I do in order to change the ".33" value into "0.33"?

Tags: command-line, bash, echo

I want to compare the value against 0 and it tells me that it is less than 0.
I used

```
solution=`echo $a / $b | bc -l`
```

This issue occurs only when "a" is less than "b".

Comment: Are $a and $b integers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8402181/2072269, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185892/70524

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bc` will not print a leading zero. You can print the output by piping it to

`awk '{printf "%0.2f", $1}'`

To summarize:

```
solution=$(echo 1 / 3 | bc -l | awk '{printf "%0.2f", $1}')
echo $solution
```

Comment: Use $(..) instead of legacy \`..\`. Read [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006).

Comment: ...or you could just do the math in `awk`, and take `bc` out entirely.

Answer (score 5):

```
a=1
b=3
printf -v solution "%.2f" $(bc -l <<< "$a / $b")
echo $solution
```

Output:

```
0.33
```

If $a and $b are always integers and you are looking for bash only solution
to divide two integers: Then you might be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24431665/3776858).

Answer (score 3):

With `printf`:

```
$ printf '%f' $(echo $a / $b | bc -l)
0.200000
```

If you want only 1  position after decimal point:

```
$ printf '%.1f' $(echo $a / $b | bc -l)
0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the leading zero using `perl`:

```
$ echo 1 / 3 | bc -l | perl -ne 'printf"%0.2f\n",$_'
0.33
```

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the wrong answer.

Comment: @A.B. No problem, they are indeed similar.

Comment: Therefore, you get a +1 =)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use perl only:

```
$ export a=1 b=3; perl -e 'printf("'%.2f'\n", $ENV{a}/$ENV{b});'
0.33
```

and for your script:

```
solution=$(export a=1 b=3; perl -e 'printf("'%.2f'\n", $ENV{a}/$ENV{b});')
echo "$solution"
```

Comment: Why using bc indeed, +1

Comment: There's a better way to pass environment variables that are valid for just one command: `a=1 b=3 perl -e 'printf("%.2f\n", $ENV{a} / $ENV{b})'`

Comment: (The relevant [Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) is rather cryptic, though.)